# SQL. Create one big table or different tables for earch client "client stock portfolio"? It is training project

Tags: mysql, sql

**What is better for multiply clients?**
I create training project and can't understand what's better. Create one big stock portfolio table for all broker's clients or create individual table for each client? Individual table will require add brokerage agreement id for each table's name for it indentification.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS portfolio;
CREATE TABLE common_portfolio (
   common_portfolio_id serial,
   brokerage_agreement_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   type_assets_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   stock_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   stock_num BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   
   FOREIGN KEY (brokerage_agreement_id) REFERENCES brokerage_agreement (brokerage_agreement_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (type_assets_id) REFERENCES type_assets (type_assets_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (stock_id) REFERENCES stock (stock_id)
);
```

**VS**

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS portfolio_12345612348; -- number generate from brokerage_agreement_id
CREATE TABLE portfolio_12345612348 (
   position_id serial,
   type_assets_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   stock_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   stock_num BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY (type_assets_id) REFERENCES type_assets (type_assets_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (stock_id) REFERENCES stock (stock_id)
);
```

Comment: One common table!

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. If the data should be kept as seperated as possible, use different databases (with the same table structure)

Comment: That's up to the client surely?

Comment: With one common table, you will not need to ask questions like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286993/how-can-i-add-columns-to-specific-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to keep all them in same table.

Keeping each client's data in a separate table will provide you with best performance only in case when you're looking for this particular customer.

But in all other cases it will be hell: creating/deleting a client will require you to build a dynamical create/drop table statement.

When sometime later you decided to add a column, you'll need to find ALL of those tables somehow and add new column to each one of them.

Even counting number of clients will cause you to write way more code rather than just "select count" statement.

And many more cases

So, use only one table

Comment: If broker has 30 millions clients and every clients has 30 stocks. It is mean 900 millions rows. One common table will be sufficient fast perfomance?

Comment: @ЕвгенийДемидов this is what databases are for: to help developers to keep and retrieve data. Table with 900 million rows is a big one but not a huge. And the databases have many different features to help you out with performance (indexes, partitions)

Comment: You calmed me down) Thank you, I will do one big table.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДемидов glad it helped. The main idea is to keep entities like clients, orders, order lines in separate tables like 'clients', 'orders', 'order_lines'. Good luck with that project

Comment: Consider client behaviour there will perhaps be very active and very inactive if so you may wish to separate them. (of course you won't know that without client input and through experience)