# Add columns to specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple tables like around 2000 tables, in that few tables are change_tracking is enabled tables. I need to add extra column to those change_tracking_enabled tables only.

My code is adding columns to all 2000 tables. I need to add columns for only CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED tables only. Please help me

1. Here is my code to display the change_tracking_enabled tables.

   ```sql
   USE Test
   GO
   SELECT s.name as Schema_name, t.name AS Table_name, tr.*
   FROM sys.change_tracking_tables tr
   INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = tr.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
   ```
2. Here is my code that adds columns to all 2000 tables.

   ```sql
   USE TestDB
   GO
   --Declare Variables
   DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
   DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(100)
   DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50)
   SET @COLUMN_NAME='ddtm' -- Change Column Name according to your requirement
   DECLARE @COLUMN_DATATYPE VARCHAR(50)
   SET @COLUMN_DATATYPE='DateTime' -- Provide data type for column

   --Declare Cursor
   DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
     SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
            TABLE_NAME
     FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   --OPEN CURSOR
   OPEN CUR
   --Fetch First Row
   FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
   --Loop
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN

     DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
     SET @SQL=NULL
     IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME=@COLUMN_NAME 
   and Table_Schema=@TableSchema)
     BEGIN
     SET @SQL='ALTER TABLE '+@TableSchema+'.'+@TableName +' ADD '+@COLUMN_NAME
                            + ' '+@COLUMN_DATATYPE
       PRINT @SQL
       EXEC ( @SQL)
     END

     IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME=@COLUMN_NAME 
   and Table_Schema=@TableSchema)
     BEGIN
     PRINT 'Column Already exists in Table'
     END
         FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
     END
   --Close and Deallocate Cursor
   CLOSE CUR
   DEALLOCATE CUR
   ```

Comment: Seems you just need to check if change tracking is enabled in the query that puts the data into your `CURSOR`. Does this answer your question? [How to check if change tracking is enabled on a specific table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182085/how-to-check-if-change-tracking-is-enabled-on-a-specific-table)

Comment: no... i need to add extra columns to change_tracking_enabled tables only.

Comment: Yes, but your query to get the data in the `CURSOR` is ***NOT*** the query you use in step 1; you ask for *all* the tables... Use the query you have in Step 1...

Comment: ya im not getting how to add that...im new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries

```sql
  SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
         TABLE_NAME
  FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

and

```sql
SELECT s.name as Schema_name, t.name AS Table_name, tr.*
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables tr
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
```

Are ***not*** the same, of course you're getting different results... Use the query you use in step 1 (minus the `tr.*`) for the query in step 2; as that gives you the tables that have CDC.

Comment: can you please send the code .....how can i do?...

Comment: Use your copy and paste feature, @Vijayashree ...

Comment: --Declare Cursor
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT s.name as Schema_name, t.name AS Table_name, tr.*
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables tr
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
  --SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
    --     TABLE_NAME
  --FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 -- WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'--
--OPEN CURSOR
OPEN CUR
--Fetch First Row
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
--Loop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

Comment: do you mean like this

Comment: The `tr.*` shouldn't be there

Comment: i got it...its working now